# How to let Makefile uses gpg passwordlessly?

Tags: security, scripting, gnupg, pgp

I have a Makefile that calls gpg to decrypt text files before opening it with a text editor for editting. Because I do it frequently, I'd like save time typing in password every time, how can I set up gpg to remember I passed the password test recently? For example, trigger me to type in password only if I haven't done it in the last 30 minutes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two ways to do this:

- let `gpg` read the passphrase from a file using the option `--passphrase-file` (but the gpg man page advises against using this option if you can avoid it! And i think you can avoid it as follows...);
- use `gpg-agent` for caching the passphrase. If the shell script requires you to enter the passphrase every time, there's likely no agent running. If a gpg-agent is running, `env | grep GPG` should give some output like `GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/gpg-6YivG1/S.gpg-agent:10479:1`. If there's no GPG_AGENT_INFO variable set, you may have to start gpg-agent manually or (preferable) configure your system to start the gpg-agent automatically. How to do this depends on your distribution. The [GnuPG Manual](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html#Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT) has some infos about this.